# Code is running when loading the editing screen for users in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the code below to add an extra button to the edit user screen to run a function on button click. However it also runs the function EnglishYellowAdd(); when loading the edit user screen instead of only on button click. Is there a way around this? The button works fine its just the extra iteration at the start.

```
add_action('edit_user_profile','EnglishYellow');
function EnglishYellow(){

?>
<button onclick="clickMe()">Lean Six Sigma Yellow Belt </button>
?><script>
function clickMe(){
var call = <?php EnglishYellowAdd();?>


}
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: post your `EnglishYellowAdd` function code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function EnglishYellowAdd() {

  global $woocommerce;

  $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];

  // Now we create the order
  $order = wc_create_order();
    
  // The add_product() function below is located in /plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract_wc_order.php
  $order->add_product( get_product('3356'), 1); // This is an existing SIMPLE product
  $order -> set_customer_id($user_id);
  //

  $order->update_status("Completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);  
}
```

Comment: I want EnglishYellowAdd basically to be run on button click in the edit user screen

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).